# Python not printing file contents in for loop

Tags: python, file

I have this code below:

```
import os

dir = os.listdir('files/')

for file in dir:
    print(file)

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        x = f.readlines()
        print(x)
```

Whenever I run it I get the following output:

```
TextFile1.txt
[]
TextFile2.txt
[]
```

In the 2nd and 4th line it is printing out an empty array even though the file has contents.

TextFile1.txt contains:

```
code 1
email 1
pw 1
```

and TextFile2.txt contains:

```
code 2
email 2
password 2
```

I'm not sure why it's printing as an empty array when the file isn't empty, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir` only returns the file names and not the full path to those files, you need to join the directory name and the file name before opening

```
import os

BASE_DIR = 'files/'
dir = os.listdir(BASE_DIR)

for file in dir:
    print(file)

    with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, file), 'r') as f:
        x = f.readlines()
        print(x)
```